# как исправить ошибку cs 4033

Tags: c#, асинхронность, return, async-await

взял с документации вот такой код:

```
static async Task<string> request(string link)
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(link);
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            return responseBody;
        }
```

но при вызове метода через `string user_ip = await request("https://ident.me");` получаю ошибку cs4033, оно пишет что метод не являеться асинхронным

Comment: использовать await можно только в async методе

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы должны вызвать данный метод из асинхронного, если же Вам это не нужно, и Вы хотите установить подключение в один поток, то просто добавьте `.Result` в конце строки и уберите await, т.е. вот так `string user_ip = request("https://ident.me").Result;`.